# Create Date Field when using Data Connection in Excel

Tags: list, excel

I noticed that the create date field of a list item is not returned when you create a data connection to it using Excel.

The technique I am using is to go to the list and export it from the ribbon to download the *.qry file.  Then use that file in Excel to create the connnection.

Does anyone know of another way to get the create date imported into excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Created Date field is in the view that the IQY is derived from. I've got a library filled with dozens of data sources from Sharepoint lists and the created filed is included be cause it was in the view when the IQY file was created.